# Flutter/StatefulWidget rebuilds Row from button child

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **StatefulWidget** that I want to update at a **Row** level, the **Row** contains many buttons which are in fact *5 stars*.

Whenever a button *star* is clicked, the data gets added to a list containing data with the same rating, but I also want to make it (the row widget) update to "rate again" to replace the first row (with stars).

I can't use the **Rating Package** because I have lists the data gets added to.
Here is the code below :

```
child: _active
      ? Row(children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<PRProvider>().add1(flist[index]);
                ;
                _handleTap;
              },
              icon:
                  Image.asset('assets/star.png', fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          IconButton(),
          IconButton(),
          IconButton()
        ])
      : Row(children: [
          Text("rate again"),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {})
        ]),
```

Comment: could you add your code too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I did, can you please check it out?

Comment: this is not a good way to get the rate, because how would you when rating finished to change the state?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I_handleTap sets the state

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Stateful widget,just change _active to false after any icon is clicked (i don't recommend this approach as the Rating row immediately disappears after user clicks)

```
child: _active
      ? Row(children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<PRProvider>().add1(flist[index]);
                ;
                _handleTap;
                setState(() { _active = false }); // this line
              },
              icon:
                  Image.asset('assets/star.png', fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          IconButton(),
          IconButton(),
          IconButton()
        ])
      : Row(children: [
          Text("rate again"),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {})
        ]),
```

Comment: Hi Sanketh, that's what I did, it's basically what handletap means. However, the widget either doesn't wait for me to click to show the update or it doesn't update at all.

Comment: @BlueMint not able to understand what do you mean by "update" here, can you please elaborate a little

Comment: Update relates to the statefulwidget changing states.

Comment: Can you post a gif, it would be more helpful to understand